# avoiding redundancy with set-up with c#/selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm just starting to learn the basics of automation through the selenium webdriver, and I am struggling to "clean up" the tests that I have written. I have each test separated into it's own case in the solution; however, as each test case has the same setup and teardown, it is evident that it would be redundant to perform both for every individual test case within the solution. Is there a way to perform the setup once before all the tests are run, and the teardown once after the tests have all run to completion?

Here is an example test case:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestCase3Final
    {
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
    private string baseURL;
    private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseURL = "http://adam.goucher.ca/parkcalc/index.php";
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestCase3()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("EntryDate")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("EntryDate")).SendKeys("01/02/2014");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ExitDate")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ExitDate")).SendKeys("01/01/2014");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("Submit")).Click();
        try
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("ERROR! YOUR EXIT DATE OR TIME IS BEFORE YOUR ENTRY DATE OR TIME", driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("b")).Text.Trim());
        }
        catch (AssertionException e)
        {
            verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
        }
    }
    private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool IsAlertPresent()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
            IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            string alertText = alert.Text;
            if (acceptNextAlert) {
                alert.Accept();
            } else {
                alert.Dismiss();
            }
            return alertText;
        } finally {
            acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: _it is evident that it would be redundant to perform both for every individual test case within the solution._ - even if it is redundant, you'll want to avoid if state is kept between separate unit tests. For example if unit test B fails if it is run after A. So it might be good that setup and teardown are executed for each test.

Answer (score 0):

By using base classes and assigning attributes to the methods so NUnit can still understand the base test fixtures.

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestCase3Final : BaseTestFixture
```

...

```
public class BaseTestFixture {
 [TestFixtureSetup]
 public void SetupStuff() {
  // set up driver here using a [TestFixtureSetup] attribute
  // it will be run for every class that inherits from it.
 }
}
```

So have a single base test fixture that all others inherit from, as long as they inherit from it then the setup methods will be called for each one.

Note, your test is from the IDE or some record-and-playback. Automation + stuff like properly "cleaning up your test" require you to have a decent knowledge of language you are using, and understanding OO principles.